# Create an object of AreaChartBuilder in JavaFX 2.2

Tags: charts, javafx

I want to create an object of `AreaChartBuilder`.
Signature of this class:

```
Class AreaChartBuilder<X,Y,B extends AreaChartBuilder<X,Y,B>>
```

I want to know the syntax to create its object.
Please help me.

Comment: I figured it out. This is how it is created.
AreaChartBuilder <Number,Number,?> acb;

acb=(AreaChartBuilder)AreaChartBuilder.<Number,Number,AreaChart>create();